# How to Azure function configure for Site-to-Site Connectivity?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

i want to configure Site-To-Site connectivity for the Azure Functions app.
Is it possible?
if yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your Function must be on an App Service Plan, not a Consumption Plan.

Then you will need to create a virtual network.

Then you configure VNET Integration on your Function to make it connect to the virtual network over a point-to-site VPN.

Then you connect your other network with site-to-site VPN to the virtual network.

And then is the critical part. The Function should already know how to route calls to IP addresses on the other network (you should see the address space in the VNET Integration). But the other network might not know about the point-to-site address space. You will have to configure your other network such that it routes traffic bound for the virtual network address space and the point-to-site address space through the site-to-site VPN connection.

Comment: Current situation is : i already have a Gateway which is Static routing, and i can not change it. the way you suggested will still possible?

Comment: No, point-to-site is not supported on static routing gateways. You need a dynamic gateway.

Comment: About the IP routing calls you maintained in answer. it this need to handle in  code?

Comment: No. The code can just call out to the IP address once the routing is configured correctly.