# How to connect to on-premise Oracle-db using Azure Functions?

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-functions, azure-hybrid-connections

I'm trying to create an Azure Function to connect and query an on-premise Oracle-DB. I can not see that the Oracle Client or an ODBC-driver is installed on the servers to handle this.

Are there any solutions to this using JS or Python?

I have tried using the node-odbc driver, but the server is missing the Oracle client.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answer for connecting to on-premise service like Oracle-db from Azure Functions, there is an existing SO thread [How to Azure function configure for Site-to-Site Connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095674/how-to-azure-function-configure-for-site-to-site-connectivity) had answered it, which you can refer to. So first, you must make sure networking access to on-premise server available.

Then, if you want to query oracle database via odbc, the oracle odbc driver must be installed on the client-side. However, the oracle odbc driver is a commerce componet, which you need to pay for getting it, and install it manually in Azure Functions. So even you want to use JS or Python to connect it, I think using Java with Oracle jdbc driver is a better solution from Azure Functions to connect Oracle DB to avoid the additional installation.

The other way I thought is to deploy a REST API app as proxy on your on-premise server to handle the query request from Azure Functions with JS or Python to help connecting Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to establish a hybrid connection. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Then you can refer to this thread to establish a context:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2434fe10-3219-4625-bdbf-b9e96421230b/entity-framework-with-oracle-and-sql

For a nodejs solution, I would add the NPM and install it using Kudu using node-oracledb:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#getstarted

// myscript.js
// This example uses Node 8's async/await syntax.

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

var mypw = ...  // set mypw to the hr schema password

async function run() {

  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(  {
      user          : "hr",
      password      : mypw,
      connectString : "localhost/XEPDB1"
    });

    let result = await connection.execute(
      `SELECT manager_id, department_id, department_name
       FROM departments
       WHERE manager_id = :id`,
      [103],  // bind value for :id
    );
    console.log(result.rows);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

sample code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but you still need to install the Oracle Client on the Azure function. Therefore it will not work, I am afraid..

Answer (score 0):

Create and deploy your code to Azure Functions as a custom Docker container using a Linux base image. Install the Oracle client libraries in custom image. Check out my blog on the topic:
https://www.ravitella.com/azure-function-container/

Comment: This link is not working anymore.