# Azure Function Oracle Connection

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-functions, azure-python-sdk

It appears that your Azure Function is working correctly on local machine but returns a 500 error when deployed to Azure Function. In Azure Function is connecting to an on-premises Oracle database.
Azure function code written in python language.

please help to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

- According to this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322812/how-to-connect-to-on-premise-oracle-db-using-azure-functions) by Peter Pan. You need to configure Site to Site VPN from your on-prem machine that hosts Oracle DB to your Azure Site where the Function is integrated with the same VNET as your VPN Gateway.
- Then Install ODBC Driver or preferably JDBC Driver for Oracle DB connection to your Function and use the JDBC connection string in your Function code to establish the connection successfully.
- Another option as answered by RCT is to Dockerize your Function by installing oracle clients in a Docker image and then running them in an azure function inside a docker.

**Sample Docker File with Oracle Client and Azure Functions:-**

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install Azure Functions Core Tools
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools-3

# Install cx_Oracle and any other Python dependencies your function needs
RUN pip install cx-Oracle

# Copy your Azure Functions code into the container
COPY . /app

# Expose the Azure Functions port (default is 7071)
EXPOSE 7071

# Start the Azure Functions host
CMD ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

**Dockerfile 2:-**

```
# Use an official Azure Functions Python runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0

# Install additional OS-level dependencies if needed
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y <package-name>

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install cx-Oracle

# Set environment variables if necessary
# ENV MY_ENV_VAR=value

# Copy the Azure Functions code into the container
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

# Expose the Azure Functions port (default is 7071)
EXPOSE 7071

# Start the Azure Functions host
CMD [ "azure-functions-core-tools", "host", "start" ]

# Start the Azure Functions host
CMD [ "func", "start" ]
```

[image]