# Azure function Connecting to Oracle database

Tags: c#, azure

I have a console application to connect and update a record on oracle. This works fine. But after copying the same function onto an azure function, I am getting Connection Timeout issue. Does anybody know if there are some set ups or other configuration required on Azure?

Below is my code block:

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        ocsb.Password = "xxxxx";
        ocsb.UserID = "xxxxx";
        ocsb.DataSource = "xxxxxxx";
        con.ConnectionString = ocsb.ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET STATUS = 20 WHERE STATUS = '30'";
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Not your problem, but you use Status as both an Int and a Varchar in the same statement!  You should also use Parameters, this would help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answer for connecting to on-premise service like Oracle-db from Azure Functions, there is an existing [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095674/how-to-azure-function-configure-for-site-to-site-connectivity) had answered it, which you can refer to.

So first, you must **make sure networking access to on-premise server** available. Following this article about using [Hybrid Connections](https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/).

Then, if you want to query oracle database via odbc, the oracle odbc driver must be installed on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

THanks for your help above,

The issue occurred because I made an update on the oracle console but did not commit. Unlike sql server, when you run an update statement, you should also run the 'commit' line of code.