# SaaS product with on-prem AD integration

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, okta

I have a SaaS product, it has it's own cloud-based authentication, and it is hosted in Azure. This works for most of my customers, but supposing a customer has their own on-prem AD - is it possible my SaaS product (cloud-hosted, external to the customer's network) can swap out my own authentication for the AD? What technologies/APIs are available to me for this?

### Further Context

This is a vue app (client-side) with a .Net back-end (.Net core API in Azure).

I'm currently using okta, I pass okta data from a login form, and it returns a token.

If I could do a straight swap with okta for AD instead and call off to the client's AD server and receive a token (on successful authentication) and then pass that token as part of every request as I do with okta, that would be ideal.

### What I've Tried

I know Okta itself has options for single-sign-on with AD, but I don't see the need for Okta if it's only going to be used as a way of interfacing to my customer's AD server, I'd like to just go 'straight there' instead.

Comment: Does the client also sync their on prem AD to Azure AD or is it only on prem?

Comment: Authenticating against AD from .NET is [fairly straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707820/how-to-use-active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-core). Yes, your app will have to change if you want to go 'straight there' but you seem to be willing to take that hit.

Comment: ...and of course, to go 'straight there' you'll need connectivity between your app deployed on Azure and on-premises AD. Lots of options there. [Hybrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) connections or [site-to-site connectivity with Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095674/how-to-azure-function-configure-for-site-to-site-connectivity) are possible. Despite documentation disclaimer to the contrary, Hybrid connection will work if you use LDAP over TCP which implies avoiding queries on root DSE in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Okta is not required to do Azure AD authentication. I have successfully completed azure ad single sign-on authentication using MSAL in Angular and Python.

Go to your `portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> APP Registration -> Select you app -> Quick Start -> Select programming language -> Click download the source code.`

To understand the code, use this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular

As you mentioned. you have used on-premise code, use the same code for authentication, this below tutorial explains how to do authentication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

Comment: They want to authenticate against an *on premise* Active Directory, not *Azure* Active Directory.

Comment: On-premise also using the same azure, so the code won't change apart configuration. - Updated the code